# Can Present Perfect be used for Past Conditional

Tags: conditionals

Does present perfect in conditional only mean future situations? Can it be used for hypothetical future?

> When I went to Africa, I thought as if I *have* already been there.
>
> If you have studied, you would pass the exam.

Comment: In a word, no. You can't.

Comment: Also, "I thought as if" is not idiomatic in most dialects of English I've heard. "I felt as if" is more usual.

Comment: To add to @KarlKnechtel "It seemed as if I had already been there."

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use it for future situations. [Here](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfect.html) is one reference and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_perfect) is Wikipedia's.

In your case you could replace the sentences as follow:

> When I went to Africa, I thought as if I have already been there. [X]
>      When I went to Africa, I felt as if I had already been there. [✔]
>
> If you have studied, you would pass the exam. [X]
>      If you had studied you would have passed the exam. [✔]

By the way, I used the 3rd conditional in the second sentence.